# Eclipse 4.2 (Juno) crashes on Ubuntu 12.04 (Precise)

Tags: eclipse, autocomplete, installation, ubuntu-12.04, dart-editor

## Problem description

I installed Eclipse 4.2 Java on Ubuntu 12.04 x86_64 and it just crashes each time the auto completion context menu is opened. It crashes without any error message and just closes the Eclipse window. Interestingly, it also crashes when I click on one of the menu points in Edit->Content Assist AND it crashes when I click in the Window->Preferences on the menu point General->Web Browser. (I experienced that because I wanted to switch off auto completion.)

Finally, I turned off auto completion but the error, as described above, is just less frequently and randomly. At each crash, it just closes the window without any error message every 5 minutes. That's absolutely unacceptable.

## Question

Does anybody have a clue what's wrong? I can provide any information you need, just let me know what you need. I can also perform steps that might seem promising to you and report the results.

## Additional Information

I have tried different versions of Java JDK, e.g. openjdk-6-jdk, openjdk-7-jdk, oracle-6-jdk, oracle-7-jdk, and different versions of eclipse, e.g. eclipse 3.7 (Indigo) and eclipse 4.2 (Juno). Nothing worked out, but maybe I did it wrong because I had to install Oracle JDK's manually.

```
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_15"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea7 2.3.7) (7u15-2.3.7-0ubuntu1~12.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)

$ javac -version
javac 1.7.0_15
```

Comment: The same problem happens in Ubuntu 13.04, Eclipse Juno, java 1.7.0_21 java version "1.7.0_21" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_21-b11) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.21-b01, mixed mode)

Comment: I switched to Netbeans instead of Eclipse. It seems to me that Eclipse is just not working on Ubuntu ...

Comment: Yep! The same on Fedora 19. Tried open jdk 1.7, oracle jdk 1.7, oralce jdk 1.6... all the same..

Answer (score 11):

This solved the problem for me (Debian jessie x64, OpenJDK 1.6.0_27)

[Answer from Bugzilla – Bug 404776](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=404776#c6)

For a workaround add the following to the end of your eclipse.ini:

`-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla`